# forEach loop to assign new value to variables in array is not replacing value of variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to loop over an array that contains three variables with a forEach loop, and change the value of each variable to a random number between 0-255.

I've started out by giving each variable a simple value:

```
let rgb1 = 1;
let rgb2 = 2;
let rgb3 = 3;
```

And then I've put those variables into an Array:

```
let rgbVariables = [rgb1,rgb2,rgb3];
```

I have my function that returns a random number between 0-255

```
function randomColor() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 255));
}
```

And lastly my function that loops over the array

```
function refreshRGBNumbers() {
    rgbVariables.forEach(function(rgb) {
      rgb = randomColor();
    });
```

The refreshRGBNumbers function is called when I click a button. I have verified that the function is being called correctly, but when I check the value of the variables in the array they remain 1,2,3.

What do I need to do here to get the function to correctly replace the array variables with the random number?

Comment: `rgbVariables.forEach(function(rgb) {
      rgb = randomColor();
    });` does nothing to the array, It does not alter the value

Comment: You can't mutate primitive values. Do `forEach((rgb, index, array) => array[index] = randomColor())` or better yet `.map(() => randomColor())`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alter the values in the array, you would need to alter it directly.

```
rgbVariables.forEach(function(val, index, array) { array[index] = randomColor(); })
```

Comment: The values in your are array are primitives, the forEach isn't passing a reference to the array element, it passes the primitive value

Comment: @epascarello when I replace my function with what you have there I have the same issue. New function: ```function refreshRGBNumbers() {
   

    rgbVariables.forEach(function(val, index, array) { 
        array[index] = randomColor(); 
    })

    console.log(rgb1);
    console.log(rgb2);
    console.log(rgb3);
}``` Returns the same 1,2,3 as before

Comment: The variables will never update, that is not how it works.

Comment: When you stick the variable in the array it is not referencing that variable, it is that value at that time.